# PowerShell accessing data from hashtable inside hashtable

Tags: powershell, hash

I have 5 hash tables:

```
$Monday = @{RUG = "";NRH1 = "";NRH2 = "";ELM = "";BAGVAGT = ""}
$Tuesday = @{RUG = "";NRH1 = "";NRH2 = "";ELM = "";BAGVAGT = ""}
$Wednesday = @{NRH1 = "";NRH2 = "";ELM = "";BAGVAGT = ""}
$Thursday = @{NRH1 = "";NRH2 = "";ELM = "";BAGVAGT = ""}
$Friday = @{NRH1 = "";NRH2 = "";ELM = ""}
```

That get filled with data. And I can get data out from these either one at at time with `$Monday.RUG` or all with `$Monday | out-string`. No problem there.

I'm going to combine those in another hash table 100 times with different data.
So it will be like this:

```
$Week = @{
1 = @{mo=$Monday;tu=$Tuesday;we=$Wednesday;th=$Thursday;fr=$Friday;val=$value}
2 = @{mo=$Monday;tu=$Tuesday;we=$Wednesday;th=$Thursday;fr=$Friday;val=$value}
}
```

And so on, until I have 100 different weeks with different values (value will be  a calculated number)

But the question is. How do I access the items in the hashtables inside the `$week` hashtable?

Is there a direct way like `$week.1.mo` ? or do you need to use a loop?

Answer (score 1):

You can access it using:

```
$Week[1].mo
```